# How to call SystemParametersInfoW function from Managed C# code

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I am looking to run the SystemParametersInfoW function, which is from a C++ API. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-systemparametersinfow#return-value).

However this method needs to be run from a C# application.

Examples linked below of pinvoke by Microsoft make no sense to me.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/calling-native-functions-from-managed-code?view=vs-2017)

How would I do this? I am relatively new to C++.

Thanks.

Comment: **why** you need to use `SystemParametersInfoW`, and are you sure there is no `c#` equivalent?

Comment: Why not just use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters?view=netframework-4.7.2?

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
[DllImport("user32"), CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]
extern "C" bool SystemParametersInfoW(
  uint  uiAction,
  uint  uiParam,
  IntPtr pvParam,
  uint  fWinIni
);
```

in general:

```
[DllImport(<dll-file of function>]
extern "C" return_value function_name(<function_parameters>);
```

Comment: *`[DllImport("user32"), CharSet=CharSet::Ansi)]
extern "C" bool SystemParametersInfoW`* `WinAPiFunctionW` is not Ansi ..